# Convert PHP code to C#

Tags: c#, php

Is there a web site or tool that will convert a piece PHP code to C#?

something similar to

http://converter.telerik.com/

or

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: I would be surprised if there was.

Comment: HipHop does it to C++ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you love .net, then you may try converting to ASP.net. syntaxes are mostly similar(Argument, guys!! :).

Otherwise you may use **Phalanger**(http://www.php-compiler.net/doku.php )

Installing this on your ASP.NET web server allows you to deploy PHP code, even full applications like wordpress.

Comment: I came across Phalanger on my travels and hoped they had a page to do the conversion, but sadly no :-(

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any such tool -- and I'd suppose that any automated tool to do that kind of "conversion" between two languages that are quite different would not do such a good job...

PHP being interpreted *(well, more or less)*, and C# being compiled, **those languages are quite not similar**... Which means an automated tool will probably not be able to convert everything *(as an example, Facebook's HipHop for PHP converts PHP to C++, but cannot convert everything -- it cannot convert `eval` and such things, for example)*, and/or will not be as good as an intelligent human-being.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread was answered already, but I wanted to contribute the `PHP to ASP.Net Migration Assistant`.  Its for 1.x, but still usable.  As mentioned, the difference in the architectures make this kind of automatic conversion an impossibility, but nothing says tools can't help.